# Non-sobel discrete gradients in python-Opencv or numpy

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I'd like to compute the discrete X and Y gradient arrays of a 2-d numpy image array according to the following masks:

```
import numpy as np
mx = np.array([[-1, 0, 1]])
my = np.array([[-1, 0, 1]]).T
```

I've looked in opencv documentation and didn't find anything other than Sobel operators which I'm not interested in. What is the fastest way to compute said gradients using either pure numpy or numpy with opencv/cv2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it, simply use `cv2.filter2D` like this:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

mx = np.array([[-1, 0, 1]])
my = np.array([[-1, 0, 1]]).T
im = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
               [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
               [3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
               [4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
               [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],]).astype(np.uint8)

gx = cv2.filter2D(im, cv2.CV_32F, mx)
gy = cv2.filter2D(im, cv2.CV_32F, my)

print gx.shape
print gx.dtype
print gx
```

which gives:

```
(5, 5)
float32
[[ 0.  2.  2.  2.  0.]
 [ 0.  2.  2.  2.  0.]
 [ 0.  2.  2.  2.  0.]
 [ 0.  2.  2.  2.  0.]
 [ 0.  2.  2.  2.  0.]]
```

Documentation can be found at: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#filter2d